# Running Several batch Commands in Sequence

Tags: windows, batch-file

When i run this batch file command as a single batch file the second command does not run.However when i run them as individual batch file commands they work fine.

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "america" -no-remote http://hakikahost.com/error.html
"nircmd.exe" win hide process "firefox.exe"
```

tried creating 1 single batch file which called with a `call` the two batch files now having separated the batch files command separately like this

```
call test.bat
call hide.bat
```

where `test.bat` contained the first command and  `hide.bat` contained the second command but it still didnt work.What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that `firefox.exe` never returns until you close the window.  Try using `start` to launch the applications, as `start` will return as soon as the application has launched.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "america" -no-remote http://hakikahost.com/error.html
start "" "nircmd.exe" win hide process "firefox.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

The first command, `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` does not return until the Fx session has ended (ie you EXIT from it)

Then there are no Fx executables so the second command can't hide the process that doesn't exist.

Try

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "america" -no-remote http://hakikahost.com error.html
"nircmd.exe" win hide process "firefox.exe"
```

The only difference is the `START ""` before the firefox-invocation. Note that the empty-quoted-string is `required` - you could enter a string between the quotes if you like - this becomes the window title.